# Fetch latitude and longitude value from firebase

Tags: android, hashmap

```
 private void setMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
            LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
                mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(location)));
            } else {
                mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
            }
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
                builder.include(marker.getPosition());
            }

        }
```

I'm getting error in
`HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();` 
.......Please help

The error in logcat is

> java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

[Database hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJkFB.png)

Comment: Show your call to firebase database code, call to this setMarker function and screenshot of database hierarchy

Comment: i have taken the code from this link.. please check https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/realtime-asset-tracking/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#5

Comment: Is your `firebase_path` string value `location`